# BLAS library incompatible with Fortran 77 compiler settings

Tags: fortran, octave, gfortran, blas

I'm trying to install Octave-3.6.2 from source on Ubuntu 12.04 with KDE desktop but when I run the Octave configure script I get this error

```
BLAS library was detected but found incompatible with your Fortran 77 
compiler settings
```

I used `./configure F77=gfortran` as was suggested by numerous web searches and I've ensured that the alternatives system F77 files are moved out of harms way as per the comments in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073199/octave-make-command-fails-with-cannot-open-file-debug-h) SO post. The installed BLAS libraries are those installed by the package manager.

What does the error mean and how do I remedy it?

Comment: Did you find an answer for this? I am getting the same error on OS X 10.8.2.

Comment: Not quite - I simply installed a different OS (Debian) and installed the latest Octave using the Debian package manager. However, I also posted this to the Octave forum and some of the responses there might be of help to you. The relevant thread is http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/BLAS-library-incompatible-with-Fortran-77-compiler-settings-td4644600.html

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23440227/octave-install-error-a-blas-library-was-detected-but-found-incompatible-with-yo/31256898#31256898) helped me with this problem.

Answer (score 5):

Try installing the Package liblapack-dev, libblas-dev, and if it exists, libblas-64.  While not Ubuntu, I had the same issue and needed to install the fedora fc20 equivalent packages which are blas-devel, blas64-devel, lapack-devel, and lapack64-devel.  The standard routine for getting the build dependencies is

```
sudo yum-builddep octave
```

While that installed most of the dependencies, I needed to follow with the following before it would completely configure.  This is from an almost scratch Fedora fc20 install with updates as of 10/23/2014.

```
sudo yum install lapack64-devel lapack64 
sudo yum install gl2ps-devel qrupdate-devel qt-devel qscintilla-devel java-devel
```

Although I did not explicitly list the blas-devel and blas64-devel packages, they were installed as dependencies of the libpack packages as was libpack-devel and plain libpack.

I suppose for Ubuntu it may be apt-get.  Either way, here is another post that talks about an earlier version of Ubuntu.

[BLAS and LAPACK libraries required for compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961340/blas-and-lapack-libraries-required-for-compiling?rq=1)

Comment: After doing `sudo yum-builddep octave ; sudo yum install lapack64-devel lapack64 ; sudo yum install libblas-dev libatlas-dev liblapack-dev ; ./configure` from `octave-4.0.0` I'm still getting this error: `configure: error: A BLAS library was detected but found incompatible with your Fortran 77 compiler settings.` Could you suggest further actions to install `octave` on `CentOS`? Thanks.

Comment: which version of centos?

Comment: CentOS release 6.7, kernel linux 2.6.32-573.18.1.el6.centos.plus.x86_64

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this problem by moving the BLAS to /usr/lib64.

Answer (score 0):

for slackware recompile blas using -libdir=/usr/lib64

Comment: I discovered my Slackware 14.1 x86_64 standard install was missing both BLAS and LAPACK. What worked for me was using the SlackBuild process for first building BLAS, and then LAPACK. Optionally, I also SlackBuilt and installed GraphicsMagick. After these dependencies were installed, I was able to build and install the SlackBuild for Octave. See http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_Slackware

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo apt-get build-dep octave`

This will install all dependencies for octave

Answer (score 0):

I was compiling octave-4.0.1 on openSUSE-12.3_x86-64 and met this problem. Before this, the blas lib (libblas3) was already installed. Then I installed the 32bit lib (libblas3-32bit), nothing changed. Then I installed the package named "blas-devel", it's resolved.

That package includes these files:

```
/usr/lib64/libblas.a
/usr/lib64/libblas.so
/usr/lib64/libblas_pic.a
```