# octave install Error: A BLAS library was detected but found incompatible with your Fortran 77 compiler settings

Tags: fortran, octave, blas, fortran77

I'm trying to install octave 3.8.1 on a cluster running Redhat+IBM LSF. I don't have write access to any directory except my home dir. I have loaded three modules 1) pcre 8.33 2) blas 08/2013 3) lapack 3.5.0. But when I run ./configure, I got the error "configure: error: A BLAS library was detected but found incompatible with your Fortran 77 compiler settings.", as the image below shows.

[image]

I have tried loading module gfortran64 and add `F77=gfortran` as command line parameter, but this doesn't work. Could you please help me with this problem? If you need any information please tell me in this webpage. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not a Fortran expert, but I remember compilers aren't [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) compatible. Do you know if your BLAS was compiled with gfortran? What GCC version?

Comment: The BLAS in the cluster is provided by the management team so I don't know how they compiled it. If I compile the BLAS by myself and use my own copy of BLAS to make octave 3.8.1, could you please show me steps of how to do it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can run the command `ldd /path/to/libblas.so` to see what compiler it was linked against. To find the library, you can type `locate libblas.so`.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to run locate libblas.so, but it returns nothing. I have already loaded blas by typing "module load blas/08_2013".

Comment: I'm not familiar with loading libraries as modules, but you can try `module show blas/08_2013` to get more information on what shell environment variables are being set. Print the output here if possible.

Comment: Thank you juliohm. I have decided to build my own BLAS and LAPACK, but there is still an error in building them. I have submitted a new question for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23463240/how-to-compile-lapack-so-that-it-can-be-used-correctly-during-installation-of-oc. Could you please take a look at it?

Comment: Just remember clusters often have an optimized build for these basic linear algebra libraries. Recompiling it yourself it not necessarily the best option.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem. On a fresh install of CentOS 6.3 I was able to compile octave 4.0.0 successfully.

After installing the necessary dependencies (notably blas, lapack and pcre) I created symlinks to liblapack and libblas in some directory, e.g.:

```
mkdir /some/path
cd /some/path
ln -s /usr/lib64/libblas.so.3 libblas.so
ln -s /usr/lib64/liblapack.so.3 liblapack.so
```

Then put the relevant directory in LDFLAGS, e.g., in bash/sh:

```
LDFLAGS=-L/some/path ./configure
```

So either octave's configure didn't look in /usr/lib64, or it requires the name of the libraries to end in ".so" (not ".so.3"). I haven't investigated which of the two was the problem since the above worked for me.

/some/path can be deleted when octave has been installed.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me too.

Answer (score 1):

My octave repository was compiling flawlessly, until the day I installed gfortran and started to get the same message. I had been using f77 (from the fort77 package). Somehow, the configure script defaulted to gfortran, which [I believe] is incompatible with the BLAS libraries.

I would suggest using f77 in octave compilation instead of gfortran.

I compiled octave 4.0.0 on Mint 17.1, but I believe the issue is the same.